# Error from declaring FT_FREETYPE_H macro

Tags: c++, freetype

I am trying to set up the freetype library; so I include ft2build.h and the FT_FREETYPE_H macro. Then I try to initialize the library with a FT_Library reference with

```
FT_Library ft;
if(FT_Init_FreeType(&ft)) {
fprintf(stderr, "Could not init freetype library\n");
return 1;
}
```

but I get an error message such as the following

```
1>  frtxt.cpp
1>c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\freetype/freetype.h(930): error C2059: syntax error : 'generic'

1>c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\freetype/freetype.h(930): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'

1>c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\freetype/freetype.h(1397): error C2059: syntax error : 'generic'

1>c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\freetype/freetype.h(1397): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'

1>c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\freetype/freetype.h(1610): error C2059: syntax error : 'generic'

1>c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\freetype/freetype.h(1610): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'

1>frtxt.cpp(8): error C2059: syntax error : 'if'

1>frtxt.cpp(8): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'

1>frtxt.cpp(8): error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
```

Comment: Can we see your `include` statement?

Comment: #include <ft2build.h>
#include FT_FREETYPE_H

Comment: See this: http://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/freetype-devel/2008-12/msg00032.html

Comment: I am using MVC10. Is there any thing I am suppose to be telling the linker??